# Tooltip does not work with pagination on datatables

Tags: javascript, jquery, pagination, datatables

How can I get my tooltip being displayed when using pagination within the datatable plugin?
I am using the plugin protip in connection with datatables to display tooltips, when text inside a column is too long. The tooltips plugin already works with the following snippet:

```
//Datatable Setup
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
var table = $('#irp-table.raab').DataTable({
    "columnDefs": [
        { visible: false, targets: 2 },
        { className: 'mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric', targets: [0, 1]}
    ],
    "order": [[ 0, 'asc' ]],
    "displayLength": 25,
    "drawCallback": function ( settings ) {
        var api = this.api();
        var rows = api.rows( {page:'current'} ).nodes();
        var last=null;

        api.column(2, {page:'current'} ).data().each( function ( group, i ) {
            if ( last !== group ) {
                $(rows).eq( i ).before(
                    '<tr class="group"><td colspan="3">'+group+'</td></tr>'
                );

                last = group;
            }
        } );
    }
} );

//Initialize ToolTip
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
$.protip();
});

//ToolTip hover behaviour
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
$('td').bind('mouseenter', function () {
  var $this = $(this);
    if (this.offsetWidth < this.scrollWidth) {

      var text = $this.text();
      $this.attr("data-pt-title", text);
      $this.protipShow()
    }
}).mouseenter();
});
```

However it just works on the first site for the case I am using pagination on my datatable and navigate to another site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### SOLUTION

You need to use [`drawCallback`](http://datatables.net/reference/option/drawCallback) to initialize tooltips every time DataTables redraws the table. This is needed because `TR` and `TD` elements for pages other than first are not present in DOM at the time first page is displayed.

Also the call to `mouseenter()` is not needed.

For example:

```js
"drawCallback": function ( settings ) {
   var api = this.api();

   // ... skipped ...

   $.protip();

   $('td', api.table().container()).on('mouseenter', function () {
      var $this = $(this);
      if (this.offsetWidth < this.scrollWidth) {
         var text = $this.text();
         $this.attr("data-pt-title", text);
         $this.protipShow();
      }
   });
}
```

#### LINKS

See [jQuery DataTables: Custom control does not work on second page and after](https://www.gyrocode.com/articles/jquery-datatables-custom-control-does-not-work-on-second-page/) for more examples and details.

Comment: Hi @gyrocode.com, you seems to be right. I also found the other answer here on stackoverflow, where someone had the same problem and your advise showed the way. However, I am struggeling to get it work on my end. May you check my fiddle? The tooltips are displayed, but on the second page every tolltip is displayed without hovering the items. https://jsfiddle.net/w6zL3kqt/

Comment: @DoUtDes, you need to remove `mouseenter()` call, see https://jsfiddle.net/w6zL3kqt/1/

Comment: thank you so much! I was searching the whole docs of the protip plugin to find the error. Thanks that you have replied again to clarify the solution, although this was a general problem with javascript rather than the origin topic!